# How to read clients and other configs from database in Duende/Identity Server?

Tags: identityserver4, duende

I have a question about Duende/Identity Sever authentication. I have been using config.cs for storing clients and other configurations.
Today, I migrated them to the Identity server database. Now, I want to get rid of Config.cs and read configs directly from the database but I don't know how I can access the ConfigureDbContext and its entities.
I assume I should make some changes to the program.cs like below but couldn't figure out what I should use instead of those commented lines below.

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
 .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
 {
    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
})
.AddOperationalStore(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
})
//.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
//.AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
//.AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
.AddMyUserStore();
```

Could you please help me with this matter?

Answer (score 0):

In duende.identity server 6.2 I configured without `AddInMemery()` it like this:
step 1
create new migrations(because they was added new tables and new fields).
script for PersistedGrant scheme:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb
```

script for Configuration scheme:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/ConfigurationDb
```

Configurations indetity server:

```
 builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlite(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlite(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);
```

as we see without `.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)` and `.AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)`, `.AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)`.

Adding a client configurations to the ours database:

```
private static void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
        if (!context.Clients.Any())
        {
            foreach (var client in Config.Clients)
            {
                context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (!context.IdentityResources.Any())
        {
            foreach (var resource in Config.IdentityResources)
            {
                context.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (!context.ApiScopes.Any())
        {
            foreach (var resource in Config.ApiScopes)
            {
                context.ApiScopes.Add(resource.ToEntity());
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Call InitializeDatabase from the ConfigurePipeline method:

```
public static WebApplication ConfigurePipeline(this WebApplication app)
{ 
    app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    
    InitializeDatabase(app);
    
    //...
}
```

You can read more in the official documentation.
[Link to official documentation](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/4_ef/)